Adding custom data to WhatsApp message in Java / Selenium
I’m using Selenium and regular scraping for a personal project, and I’m trying to send a message in WhatsApp with custom data. So far, I’ve done the usual Selenium setup, but now I want to add custom data that can’t be added with plain Selenium. I want to include mention data in the message while keeping the message content separate. I know this can be done with a JavaScript script, but I want to keep it Java-only as I’m not very familiar with JavaScript.

it might be helpful if you included the Javascript that does what you want.  Are you using WhatsApp's API?  What is this "custom data"?

@browsermator I don’t have the script, I just know it’s possible. Also I told you, right now only Selenium… by custom data I mean adjusting the json that contains the messages to somehow add the mentions with out adding them to the message content
